# Why scikit learn is using log base e in idf?

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf

I read that for scikit-learn `tf-idf` transformation, `idf` is calculated as

```
idf=log(N/df) +1
```

When I try to check the python result and manual calculation, I found out that log is using base e.
 
Why does scikit-learn` use base e? From what I know usually for idf it's using log 2 or log 10.